# CUDA memset in Compute Visual Profiler

Tags: cuda

I use Compute Visual Profiler to measure the performance of my CUDA programs.

The result of the profiler shows 2 different results for the cudaMemset function.

1. memset32_post
2. memset128

I want to know what is the difference between these 2?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that the memset128 kernel does the bulk of the work and the memset32_post kernel cleans up the remainder since you used a size that is not a multiple of 128.

There's nothing to worry about, it's just trying to implement the memset in the most efficient manner possible, although I'd try to avoid memset in an inner-loop (on any processor). If you're really worried about this you could over-allocate.